# How to implement `allowed lateless` in flink sql?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

As I know, [`allowed lateless`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#allowed-lateness) is only implemented in DataStream API, but not implemented in Flink Sql table api.

So, my question is: does it have some workaround or something else can implement this
`allowed lateless` function in flink sql table api?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the [`CURRENT_WATERMARK`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/) function in Flink SQL as an intermediate step.

For example, if you want to filter out late data you can use:

```
WHERE
  CURRENT_WATERMARK(ts) IS NULL
  OR ts > CURRENT_WATERMARK(ts)
```

For all other topics on handling late events you can track https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10031

Comment: Thank you  for your answner, I known `CURRENT_WATERMARK`, but if I use it, I need to use the late data to do extra work to revise my data etc. So, I don't want it, I want it can just fire again together with flink job executes with no late data, no need further processing. This is what the `allowed lateness` does.

Comment: Like I've mentioned, for that you have to track the Jira ticket I've included in the answer. There's currently no-one working on it though.

Edit: the only thing you could consider is starting in the DataStream API, build your allowed lateness logic there and then continue the processing in the Table API.